# Need a function to reverse an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, function, return

I need to create a function that receives an array items and reverses the order of items in the array and returns it.

Basically if I have an array ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'worm'] the function should return an array of ['worm','bird','dog','cat'].

So far I get lost in the function language... I have this.

```
       //Split a string into an array of substring
        string avengersNames = "Thor;Iron Man;Spider-Man;Hulk;Hawk Eye";

        //Creat an array to hold substring
        string[] heroArray = avengersNames.Split(';');

        foreach (string hero in heroArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hero);


        }


    //Parameter is Array of items
    //At a loss when trying to incorporate an array into this function.
    public static string[] heroList = new string[5];
    {

    }
```

Comment: Besides knowing the built-in functions do remember that `foreach` is often useful and __often useless__. With a regular `for` loop you would have had not trouble doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Array.Reverse(heroArray); // can do trick for you
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.Reverse` function

```
string[] heroArray = avengersNames.Split(';');
Array.Reverse(heroArray );
```